# Can you access Bluetooth on smartphones without writing any native code?

Tags: android, iphone, ios, blackberry, bluetooth

This is for a research project at school so this is somewhat urgent. We need to know if this technology exists, or if it would require us to build something native for each device.

Is it possible to use any frameworks or tools to access Bluetooth sensors from a non-native application. For example, I gather that HTML5 applications will can access some sensors, but need bridging frameworks to access others (i.e. PhoneGap). Are there any other apps that have tackled this problem in the past that we can research?

Comment: I don't think this is possible on the iPhone even with native code. Bluetooth use is very restricted.

Comment: I've heard about GameKit (in another answer to this question as well as in other forums). This seems to require native code and gives access, but how do you mean that it is restricted?

Comment: The GameKit functionality is exclusively intended to enable local multiplayer information sharing between people playing the same game without requiring a WiFi hotspot or roundtrips through the network. It doesn't give you free reign to connect to your sensors, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

With iOS you need to use it through GameKit, and even then there are big restrictions. With android your application has to specifically request access to bluetooth with permissions.

Comment: What kind of restrictions are we talking here? I'm looking into it, and it also appears to require native code. Is this the case (I've really only done Android dev myself)

Comment: Would require objective c, the largest message size allowed with GameKit is 87 kilobytes, however gamekit only works to connect iOS devices so if you are trying to create something cross platform then you need to take another approach. The BluetoothManager class may be another option, but it's a private framework and will cause a rejection from the app store.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I searched, it's not possible to use raw HTML5 to access to mobile native features such as Bluetooth on mobile devices. The only way so far that I have found is to use cross-platform mobile application development or native apps. Just keep in mind that not all cross-platform frameworks support all phone native features like Bluetooth. I think the one you mentioned, PhoneGap, does not support Bluetooth. It would be great to put comments if have you come up with any solution for your post.

Check [this link](http://www.markus-falk.com/mobile-frameworks-comparison-chart/) to get some idea about different frameworks and their features.